# Close Alert View Via Code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uialertview

I've got an alert:

```
UIAlertView *connectionError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Connection Failed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

I want to know how I can programatically close an alert view when I hit a certain event in my code. I know there is no distinct call to just close out an alert, and I've seen people make calls straight to buttons, however, I'm not sure how to call the cancel button on an alert.

Is this even the right way to go about it? Or is there a better path?

Comment: Hah, yes. Actually, I'm sweeping the success under the carpet and showing the error. I just used the error alert as my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` method for dismissing alert view:

```
[connectionError dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: connectionError.cancelButtonIndex
                                      animated: YES];
```

That's the only public API for dismissing alerts, so you should use it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare you alert view in .h file

then call this function

```
[connectionError dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps..